# Heteroduplex and Products of cleavage of Holliday Junction (Resolution)

Tags: dna, recombination, recombinant

In homologous recombination (Holliday model), the last process i.e resolution can occur in two ways (horizontl and vertical cuts) leading to formation of either "splice" or crossover products or "patch" or non-crossovers product (as shown in the image). 
The two possible products confuse me with what are crossovers. I could not understand why the "patch" product (Fig. (g) in the image) is called a non-crossover. Is it because one strand of both the homologous helices are same?
Also please do explain what is the hetero-duplex in this model?

[image]

Comment: Hello @SanjuktaGhosh.
My question did come out to be a duplicate. My apologies.
The question you linked is exactly what I wanted to know. I read your answer to the same. But I still couldn't understand the concept. Can you please elaborate on the complimentary part?
Thank you.

Comment: Yeah. I'll. Give me some time. I'll elaborate as soon as I have some time.

Comment: I'm done explaining my answer you may go through it now.